# Git bash and Msys64 is same..?

Tags: git-bash, mingw-w64, msys

What is the difference between Git Bash and Msys64? I have installed them both but now I'm having doubts as to whether they are the same thing or not. Is there any issue with using both git at the same time.

Comment: IIRC git bash is a stripped down [MINGW64 environment of MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/), without a package manager and with git installed.

Comment: If you already have MSYS2 you probably don't need Git Bash, since the latter is a subset of the former, as @HolyBlackCat mentioned.